# PHP regex - having trouble writing a regex expression to match multiple specific patterns at once

Tags: php, regex, variables, file-get-contents

I'm using `file_get_contents()` on PHP scripts to auto-list variable names in order of appearance using `preg_match_all()` then filtering them by first appearance using `array_filter()`. I need to be able to catch variables in the following formats (where any variable name contains the characters `[a-zA-Z_-\d]`):

```
//standard variables
$variable
```

So far I've written a simple regex expression that fits all of my requirements for this single stand-alone variable: `[a-zA-Z_-\d]`

```
//arrays
$array[0]
$array2[$key]

//form and session variables
$_GET['frm']
$_SESSION['user']
$_POST[$var]
etc...
```

I've attempted to do the arrays and (form/session) variables myself and have got to an expression of `([$][a-zA-Z_-\d]+\[?\'?[$]?[a-zA-Z_-\d]+\'?\]?)` see http://regex101.com/r/dO8tI2 for a demonstration of how I've got this far. However I am now catching things I don't want (and I'm not sure how to adjust for this...) - i.e. the bracket on match 7, How do I only select the text `$test` and not `$test]` if there is no starting `[`. - so on and so forth for variable variables also...

```
//variable variables
${$var."a"}
${$var.$var2}
${"a"."b"}
${$var."a".$var3}
etc...
```

Where the character " is used in the examples above, also the character ' would also need to be accepted instead.

As I am fairly new to regex and am stuck at the point of the hyper-link above in my steps to my expression, could someone write a single regex expression that fits the above criteria and explain briefly how it works?

I've tried playing around with the OR `|` operator and non-caught groups (`?;` conditions...) however I'm going around in circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with following regex that match your requirements:

```
(\$[a-zA-Z_-\d]+(\[('[^']+'|\$?[a-zA-Z_-\d]+)\])?)
```

Explanation:

1. `\$` : catch `$` literally
2. `[a-zA-Z_-\d]+` : followed by one ore more alphanumeric characters or dash or underscore.
3. `(\[('[^']+'|\$?[a-zA-Z_-\d]+)\])?` : Followed by zero or one string which starts with `[` and ends with `]` and between brackets has string matching `'[^']+'` **OR** `\$?[a-zA-Z_-\d]+`. Let's break apart those 2 substrings:

   - `'[^']+'` : matches any string between single quotes.
   - `\$?[a-zA-Z_-\d]+` : matches any string that optionally starts with `$` and contains one or more alphanumeric characters, dashes and underscores.